# Laravel 5.3 Cannot find login page

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3, controllers

I am just beginning to learn laravel and I have been looking all over for this answer. I was following a tutorial step by step to get it started and I have it running the welcome screen but if I click login or register it says that the file doesnt exist. However if I make the route.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('auth/login');
});
```

It finds the page and displays it.

here is the link to the login page.

```
<div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">List of Game of Thrones Characters</div>

                @if(Auth::check())
                  <p>Success</p>
                @endif


        </div>
        <?php
             echo getcwd() . "\n";
        ?>

        @if(Auth::guest())
          <a href="/login" class="btn btn-info"> You need to login to see the list  >></a>
        @endif
```

In the href tag I have tried /auth/login, /login, and any combo you can try and it will not find the file no matter what. Here is the route I am trying to get this to work.

```
Route::get('/login', function() {
   return view('auth/login');
}
```

Can anyone explain why this isnt working? I have looked everywhere and it seems to be the correct way to call this. Remember I have just gotten the beginning templates to work.

Comment: Does it work if you change the anchor tag to `index.php/login`? If it does, then you need to setup a URL rewrite that rewrites all requests to `index.php`.

Comment: Did you forget to add closing braces and a semicolon like so: `);`

Comment: Yeah that works! How would I go about doing that?

Comment: What web server are you using? Nginx or Apache?

Comment: I use apache...

Comment: So apparently my .htaccess file in apache is messed up and not rendering the rewrites like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup web server rewrites in your webserver.

The simplest way to handle that is to use a `.htaccess` file in your `public/` directory. This is the default `.htaccess` file for Laravel 5.3:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

You also need to ensure that the `mod_rewrite` Apache module is enabled. You can do that by running these two commands which enable the module and restart Apache:

```sh
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Had to enable to apache rewrite also. Thank you